# What statistical concepts are used in introductory econometrics?

Tags: econometrics

I am an undergraduate taking an upper-year introductory course in econometrics. I have taken calculus but I am not familiar with mathematical statistics.

What are the basic concepts from statistics that I can read up on in preparation for the course? I am familiar with the idea of distributions but my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: I'll vote to close this one. Way too broad and at way too low a level. If you want to prepare for an introductory economics course, brush up on your maths in general. The stronger your statistics background is, the better. Hypothesis testing is always a good thing to improve in.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by mathematical statistics. What is the difference between statistics and mathematical statistics? Regressions and probability theory?

Comment: Start with Darrell Huff: http://www.horace.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/How-to-Lie-With-Statistics-1954-Huff.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'll list the statistics-related topics from my basic econometrics course.

- Expected value, mean, variance and covariance as well as conditional expectation and conditional variance.
- Basic probability and probability density functions (I'd suggest getting somewhat familiar at least with Normal, Student's T, and F distribution and maybe Bernoulli, Chi-Square and Poisson) and what random variables mean.
- The central limit theorem (closely related with PDFs).
- Correlation. Also understanding why correlation does not imply causation is useful, but you'll probably discuss this in class.
- Methods of regression/estimation. You'll probably be introduced to Ordinary Least Squares early on and a basic understanding of what regression models are for might be useful although probably not assumed.
- Statistical hypothesis testing. This will probably be a main subject in any applied econometrics course, so you might take a sneak peek on the basics.

You might have to understand some matrix and equation algebra depending on how theoretical the lecturer makes the course, but these were probably included in your calculus course.